# Apply a variable operation, depending on groups using tidyverse [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm not quite sure even how to google my question, so I think an example is best to explain what I want to achieve. In summary, I'd like to multiply each value of a data frame, grouped by some variable, and the multiplication value will depend on which group is it. I'll place down an example:

```
    data <- data.frame(group = c("a", "b", "c"), value = c(1, 2, 3))
    multiplier <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

    data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    // Something that multiplies the value column by the corresponding multiplier contained in the vector
```

EDIT:

The expected returned values to replace the value column should be 1, 4, 9 respectively to the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(value = value * multiplier[as.character(group)])
#  group value
#1     a     1
#2     b     4
#3     c     9
```

Alternatively, you could append `multiplier` as a column of `data` and then calculate.

```
data %>%
    mutate(mutiplier = multiplier[as.character(group)]) %>%
    mutate(new.value = value * multiplier)
#  group value mutiplier new.value
#1     a     1         1         1
#2     b     2         2         4
#3     c     3         3         9
```

Comment: Thanks!!! What about if the multiplier value lives on a data frame, with the group in one column and the multiplier on the other one, it would be similar to the solution you showed or it's just better to pass the multiplier to a vector and name it as the groups?

Comment: Interesting question. I almost assigned the multiplier as a column in the data.frame. I will edit my answer with a `dplyr` approach to that.

Comment: Seems like a very interesting approach! correct me if I'm wrong, if for example the multiplier vector differs from the data frame length, then by adding that columns, all entries of group "a" for example will have the corresponding multiplier to the group repeated for all observations it has? Hopefully I explained myself

Comment: Correct. Consider `data = data.frame(group = rep(c("a","b","c"),each=2), value = 1:6)`. The `multiplier` column in that case would be `c(1,1,2,2,3,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can do

```
transform(merge(data, stack(multiplier), by.x = 'group', by.y = 'ind'),
        value = value * values)[-3]
#   group value
#1     a     1
#2     b     4
#3     c     9
```